# Does windows Azure ACS WIF .net 4.5 support a relying party with WIF 3.5?

Tags: .net, azure, single-sign-on, wif

I am thinking of implementing SSO using Azure access control. But some of the web applications are in .net 3.5. Does Azure ACS based STS support WIF 3.5 Relying Party?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Its less a matter of ACS supporting .NET 3.5, but rather its a matter of WIF supporting .NET 3.5 (it does) because WIF is what your web application will be using to talk to ACS. You can find the WIF 3.5 SDK from the link below, which includes federation utilities and code samples.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4451